# Initializing a two-dimensional array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I wonder What is the difference between this two different method of 2D matrix initialization in python.

```
    m =[]
    K = []
    for x in range(0,W+1):
        m.append(0)
    for x in range(0,n+1):
        K.append(m)
```

and

```
    l = []
    for j in range(0,n+1):
        l.append([])
        for i in range(0,W+1):
            l[j].append(0))
```

when I tried to print l and K the both gave the same answer but when I tried to implement it in code the output of program changed.

the earlier one(K) gave an incorrect answer but later one(l) when implemented in the program gave a correct answer.

Comment: You achieved it more explicitly, but you have the same problem the list multiplying folks had in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first one, you are storing the same reference to list `m` in `k`. Change in `m` will be reflected in all the reference.

Where as in second, you are creating new lists in `l`. Hence, change in one is independent of another.

Alternatively, simpler way to initialize list is as:

- *Holding same reference to `list`* (similar to your first approach) is as:

  ```
  >>> row, columns = 2, 3
  >>> my_list = [[0]*columns]*row
  >>> my_list
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
  >>> my_list[0][1] = 1  # changing value
  >>> my_list
  [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
  #    ^          ^ Reflected in all
  ```
- *Holding different reference to the list* (similar to your second approach) is as:

  ```
  >>> my_list = [[0]*columns for i in range(row)]
  >>> my_list
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
  >>> my_list[0][1] = 1   # changing value
  >>> my_list
  [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
  #    ^  only one value is changed
  ```